# How to fix CORS issue between webflow and netlify

Tags: cors, netlify, webflow

I have deployed my first netlify site that simply returns a few records from airtable:

https://codefy-airtable.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/courses

it also works with a redirect I set up:-

https://codefy-airtable.netlify.app/api/courses

However, when I add an axios get function to my header script in webflow to test it I get a CORS error:-

> “Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> ‘https://codefy-airtable.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/courses’
> from origin ‘https://mgl-community.webflow.io’ has been blocked by
> CORS policy: No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the
> requested resource.”

[mgl-community.webflow.io](https://mgl-community.webflow.io)

Make Give Live | Community
This is my function:-

```
   axios.get('https://codefy-airtable.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/courses')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log('axios ', response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Axios ', error);
  });
```

This is my github repo https://github.com/jonathanlyon/airtable-temp that shows the _header file with:-

```
/*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

and the .toml file with:

```
[[headers]]
for = "/*"
[headers.values]
Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*"
```

[image: deploy results]

Any idea why I can’t use the json data returned from the URL please?

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way to add headers to my code and now it works. Seems that despite having a _header file and adding headers to the .toml file in Netlify it didn't do the trick.

In my api return I added headers:-

```
module.exports = (statusCode, body) => {
    return {  
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
      };

    };
```

Comment: So you need `headers` in three parts to solve the `cors`? a) `netlify.toml` b) `_headers` c) `handler function`. There is `handler()` missing which is needed as of today with `import { Handler } from '@netlify/functions'`.

Comment: In my case, one of the three files mentioned in my last comment has to be prepared for `cors` and then it works with `localhost/.netlify..`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your API,
install cors with:  npm install cors,
then in your middleware:

```
import cors from 'cors'

app.use (cors ())
```

Comment: The answer does not help at all, because `express` is not used. Welcome to so.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and found that the problem is due to the limitation "10 second execution limit for synchronous serverless functions" (reference: https://docs.netlify.com/functions/overview/)

My finding is that, after the Netlify function was called after 10 seconds, the Netlify function will continue to run, however, the response contains the **body**

> TimeoutError: Task timed out after 10.00 seconds new TimeoutError
> (D:\yourModule\node_modules\netlify-cli\node_modules\lambda-local\build\lib\utils.js:110:28)
> Context.
> (D:\yourModule\node_modules\netlify-cli\node_modules\lambda-local\build\lib\context.js:110:19)
> listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17) processTimers
> (internal/timers.js:497:7)

[Body of response (by Postman)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Ul5.png)

and the **header** with only keys "x-powered-by", "date", "connection" and "content-length".

[Header of response (by Postman)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JOzK.png)

Since there is no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header, the browser shows the error message

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/yourFunction/' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

In Firefox, the error message is

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8888/.netlify/yourFunction/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

However, the root cause is not the CORS setting in server. The error message may direct you to the wrong direction.